# My Function returns a triangle with the size that the user inputs but i am getting a random error

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

I am assigned to make a pyramid based upon a number given by the user. Although I am close, I keep getting a random undefined error at the end of my code still. My pyramid is even executing properly.

```
function makeLine(length) {
    var line = "";
    for (var j = 1; j <= length; j++) {
        line += "* ";
    }
    return line;
}

function buildTriangle(index)
{


    for (var i=1; i<index; i++)
    {

        console.log(makeLine(i));
    }

}

console.log(buildTriangle(5));
```

When I try to show how the pyramid looks by typing it, it doesn't appear. Best way to describe it is if I enter 5, an asterisk should appear on the first line. Then 2 on the 2nd and 3 on the 3rd line. This continues until i hit 5.

Comment: Can you provide more info about the error you're seeing?

Comment: yes. I am getting my pyramid to appear correctly. Then immediately after that in a new line is just says undefined. I am not sure why despite scanning my code several times.

Comment: `console.log(buildTriangle(5));` will display `undefined` because `buildTriangle()` do not return anything. Just do `buildTriangle(5)` without the log to the console.

Comment: worked perfectly thanks for the help guys.

Comment: just curious, i should never have a console.log inside the function and then use it to print again later like i did this time?

Comment: i realized i lacked a return statement but i wasn't too sure how else to use the makeLine(i) git into the buildTriangle function

Comment: You could either use your `buildTriangle` function to build and return the string, then log the result or, as above, log directly from the function.

Answer (score 1):

The undefined is coming from the `console.log(buildTriangle(n))` line. You're trying to log the output of the function (which is undefined).

Simple fix is to remove the `console.log()` surrounding the `buildTriangle(n)` at the end of your file.